# iOS: Download large file and decrypt it in eg. didReceiveData

Tags: ios, encryption, asihttprequest, afnetworking

I've got the task to improve security in a document sharing app. The files on the server needs to be encrypted and when the app downloads a file, it would be desirable if the decryption did happend simultaneously with the file download in eg. `didReceiveData`. Some customers has video files at just under the systems limit at 500 MB.

Right now files are downloaded with the old [ASIHTTPRequest](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/) because of the built-in support of resuming downloads (`setAllowResumeForFileDownloads`).

I found this brilliant framework [RNCryptor](https://github.com/rnapier/RNCryptor) which has support for async decryption. Here is a sample using pure `NSURLConnection`:

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse (NSURLResponse*)response {
    self.decryptor = [[RNOpenSSLDecryptor alloc] initWithSettings:kRNCryptorAES256Settings password:password handler:^(RNCryptor *cryptor, NSData *data) {
        [self writeData:data];
        
        if (cryptor.isFinished){
            [self finishAndPlayVideo];
        }
    }];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data {
    [self.decryptor addData:data];
}
```

The problem is that `RNCryptor` has this `NSMutableData *inData` which it appends all the data, but this gives huge memory issues. The data needs to flow though streams like in the old version 1.1 of [RNOpenSSLCryptor.m](https://github.com/rnapier/RNCryptor/blob/RNCryptor-1.1/RNCryptor/RNOpenSSLCryptor.m#L185).

Does anyone have a solution to manipulate the `RNCryptor`, `ASIHTTPRequest` (or `AFNetworking`) code to download and decrypt huge files simultaneously?

## Update 1:

As @warrenm points out the `RNCryptor` category on [NSMutableData](https://github.com/rnapier/RNCryptor/blob/master/RNCryptor/RNCryptor.m#L35) should help on the memory usage. I can't figure out if that is the culprit.

## Update 2:

I found the culprit. I was preparing my test project to make sutable for others to run. I did change the download url from a fast coporate server to dropbox and all of a sudden the memory usage went down. This means that the app is downloading faster than it can decrypt the data and thus building up a buffer. I never though of this as an issue. Thanks to @warrenm for leading the way.

## Test project

https://dl.dropbox.com/u/195602/stackoverflow/OnlineDecryptTest.zip
Toggle the constants `kUseFastServer` and `kUseEncryption` in `ViewController.m` to see the different memory usage cases.

## Solution

The solution is to make the download and decrypt a 2 step process or do some magic with `NSInputStream`/`NSOutputStream`. I would perfer the latter but I can't figure out how to do it.

Comment: It looks like RNCryptor does the right thing by keeping no more data in memory than is necessary for the current decrypt operation. It **does** have a mutable data member to which it appends the incoming bytes, but it also uses a category on `NSMutableData`, `_RNConsumeToIndex`, that flushes the consumed bytes off the front of the `inData` object. Can you verify you're actually seeing excessive memory usage in practice with this class?

Comment: Profiling the app with Instruments shows a memory usage comparable to the file size of the downloaded file :-/

Comment: In my test app the memory usage after 31 seconds is 5.5 MB without and 99.5 MB with encryption when download a ~100MB video file. See these screenshots of Instruments: [without encryption](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/195602/Screenshots/without%20encryption.png), [with encryption](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/195602/Screenshots/with%20encryption.png)

Comment: You are totally right, self.inData is stripped down. But the memory usage rises anyway. `2013-01-02 16:04:47.201 OnlineDecryptTest[7707:c07] self.inData.length: 49232
2013-01-02 16:04:47.202 OnlineDecryptTest[7707:c07] File size: 95.08 MB (memory: 72.80 MB)
2013-01-02 16:04:47.230 OnlineDecryptTest[7707:c07] self.inData.length: 118736
2013-01-02 16:04:47.231 OnlineDecryptTest[7707:c07] self.inData.length: 41992
2013-01-02 16:04:47.232 OnlineDecryptTest[7707:c07] File size: 95.08 MB (memory: 72.67 MB)
2013-01-02 16:04:47.232 OnlineDecryptTest[7707:c07] self.inData.length: 2896`

Comment: Unless I'm misreading your logs, the length of the data is not monotonically increasing. Might there be something else contributing to the memory pressure, such as a file that's not getting flushed or an in-memory store?